# Algorithm for Floating point conversion format IEEE

Tags: floating-point, floating-point-conversion

Assuming i have a floating point (fp)  of a given format FA (i.e. with his exponent size, mantissa size), and more specifically something like

```
FA fa;
```

and suppose i wanted this to a format FB with an operation FA2FB, which gives a floating point number fb, i.e. something like

```
FB fb = FA_2_FB(fa);
```

At best of your knowledge does the IEEE standard provide a general way to perform this casting? (it could be a narrowing a widening or simply a format change, with the same amount of bits.

Is it clear my question?
If the standard doesn't provide anything i will specify which cases i'm considering.

Comment: No answer? Pleeeeease help me!

Comment: I don't seem to be able to access IEEE xplore today, so I can't answer questions that require the standard. Would you be interested in an answer based on knowledge and non-standard documentation?

Comment: Out of clarity... you talk about the IEEE 754-2008 isn't? Could be fine a non standard one, at present.

Comment: Yes. I assumed you mean IEEE 754-2008. I have a paper copy of IEEE 754-1985, but that has been superseded.

Comment: Your assumption is correct =D. My apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am copying the terminology from the Wikipedia article [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

I think the best approach to this is to split it into four problems:

1. Identify NaN and infinite input, and directly generate the corresponding bit pattern in the destination format.
2. Given a number input, extract the sign, significand, and exponent
3. Check for overflow and subnormal in the new format. If overflow, generate the appropriate infinity. If subnormal, calculate the number of bits to keep in the significand.
4. Pack into the new format. That may require rounding if the new significand has fewer bits than the old one.

You will need to select one of the standard rounding modes. The simplest is rounding towards zero, which is simple truncation. However, I recommend round to nearest with the midpoint rounded to even. For that, you need to look both at the value of the first dropped bit, and also whether there are any non-zero bits beyond it.

Comment: I agree that the approach is that, but i need to understand if there's a standard the specify something that i don't know. such "something" could potentially entails some change in my implementation. For example... suppose you have to convert from a mantissa M=30 to M=23, same exponent size, In such case should i perform a particular kind of rounding? (i basically chop off some digits). I guess i should use in this case round,guard and sticky bit.

Comment: The standard specifies multiple rounding modes. including rounding towards zero which is what you get if you just chop off digits. The one that is used most often is round-to-nearest with the midpoint rounding to even. That is best done with guard and sticky bits.

Comment: What about the exponent treatment?

Comment: In step 1, you need to test it for being the NaN and Infinity exponent for the source format. In step 2, you will subtract the source format bias to get the actual signed exponent. In step 3, you check for the exponent being too large or small for the output format. In step 4, add the bias for the result format.

Comment: A question.. Assuming i want convert a FP_N 'x' to FP_M 'y' were N > M, but mantissa size are the same, so basically only the exponent format differs, let's assumer moreover 'x' is a normal number. After the conversion is performed it is possible 'y' is a sub normal number?

Comment: If the new exponent is wider than the old one, normal inputs will map to normal results. Some subnormal inputs will also map to normal results.

Comment: And what about the converse situation?

Comment: Then the converse applies. If the new exponent is narrower, some normal input numbers will map to subnormal results. Some inputs will underflow to zero.

Comment: However, I think you are making a mistake in thinking in terms of direct conversion. Think instead, as suggested in my answer, in terms of mapping an input to a sign-exponent-significand triple, and packing a sign-exponent-significand triple to a destination format. That way, you only have to think about, and write code for, one format at a time.

Comment: I'm trying but honestly i'm kind of confused in this "packing process". If you are referring to step 4 of your pseudocode could you please be more specific in the implementation of such step?

Comment: To get a feeling for all this, you may find it helpful to experiment with an IEEE 754 analyzer, such as the one at (http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/)

Comment: I try, then i will post some pseudocode. I don't know if here i can write math formulas

Comment: I suggest starting with the easy case of numbers that are normal in both formats. Also, if you begin by converting each way between the usual 64-bit and 32-bit formats it will be easy to check your results.

Comment: I started by dinstinguish 4 case, legend:
    FPX -> Floating Point format X
    MX -> Mantissa size for FPX
    EX -> Exponent size for FPX

the 4 cases are:

    if(EA >= EB && MA >= MB) {
     ...
    } else if(EA >= EB && MA < MB) {
     ....
    } else if (EA < EB && MA >= MB) {
     ....
    } else {....}

The last two i guess are easier, while the first two are more complex.
I'm going to post some pseudocode soon.

Comment: You are still thinking in terms of both formats at once. I have no problem with you choosing a different route from my answer, but I am not going to put much effort into helping with your current approach.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't mean to bother you. But basically i have to distinguish that 4 cases, for technical reasons related to the fact i know that relationship at compile time mainly. But inside each if statement  i'm applying your suggestion. I'm going to post the most complicated one.

Comment: Hi i followed your suggestion, instead to distinguish case i worked following your route, it's better and more general of course. I've performed some test and it worked. I'm going to attach the code for further reference. Thank you for your help.